# how to obtain token with Microsoft Graph & Power BI Service scope together

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, powerbi-api

I want to obtain a token for graph api and power bi service api, tried to make scope parameter as below

> https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
> https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default offline_access

but it give error

> The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
> https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default offline_access is
> not valid

Comment: what can think about so far is, only use one /.default scope when first obtain token. then when need use different service, change the scope and refresh token.

Comment: this scenario is not supported by Azure Active Directory. You cannot obtain access token for more than one app